# Not getting Firebase token id when calling getIdToken in Swift 5 iOS

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have been trying to make this work for 3 days now, and I can't see where I am going. When trying to get firebase tokenId using the `- (void)getIDTokenWithCompletion: (nullable void (^)(NSString *_Nullable __strong, NSError *_Nullable __strong))completion;` function provided by firebase I am getting nothing in return.

I have created a separate class to get the Id using a completion handler. Below is the code I am using

```
import Foundation
import FirebaseAuth

class FirebaseToken  {
    static var shared = FirebaseToken.init()
    func getIdToken(token completion: @escaping(String?,Error?) -> Void){
        Auth.auth().currentUser?.getIDToken(completion:{ idToken, error in
            guard let error = error else {return }
            print(error)
            completion(nil, error)
            guard let token = idToken else {return}
            completion(token, nil)
            print(token)
        })

    }
}
```

This is the class I am using to call the `func getIdToken` function to get the Id, which is inside the `func makeAPICall<T:Codable>(urlPath: String, apiMethod: HTTPMethod, expectedReturnType: T.Type,user completionHandler: @escaping ([T]?,Error?)` function.

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire
import Firebase

class ApiService {
    
    static var shared = ApiService.init()
    
    let session: Session = {
        let manager = ServerTrustManager(allHostsMustBeEvaluated: false,evaluators: ["localhost": DisabledTrustEvaluator()])
        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.af.default
        
        return Session(configuration: configuration, serverTrustManager: manager)
    }()

    //MARK:- GET
    func makeAPICall<T:Codable>(urlPath: String, apiMethod: HTTPMethod, expectedReturnType: T.Type,user completionHandler: @escaping ([T]?,Error?) -> Void) {
        var urlComponent = URLComponents()
        urlComponent.scheme = "https"
        urlComponent.host = "localhost"
        urlComponent.port = 5001
        urlComponent.path = "/api/" + urlPath
        print(urlComponent.url!)
        guard let url = urlComponent.url else {
            return
        }
        
        var headers: HTTPHeaders?
        FirebaseToken.shared.getIdToken(token: {tokenId, error in
            guard let errors = error else {return}
            print(errors)
            guard let tokens = tokenId else {return}
            headers = [
                .authorization(bearerToken: tokens),
                .accept("application/json")
            ]
        })
        
        guard let headerAuth = headers else {
            print("not getting firebase token")
            return
        }
        print(headerAuth)
        session.request(url, method: apiMethod).validate().responseDecodable(of: [T].self) {(response) in
            switch response.result{
            case .success:
                guard let users = response.value else {
                    return
                }
                //print(header)
                completionHandler(users, nil)
            case .failure(let error):
                completionHandler(nil, error)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the variable `var headers: HTTPHeaders?`, which inside the function

```
guard let headerAuth = headers else {
        print("not getting firebase token")
        return
    }
```

should be printing out the token yet, for some reason the token isn't being added. Can someone let me know where I am going wrong as I have been stuck for 3 days and I am still very new to firebase?

The printing result should be within `print(headerAuth)`, however; I keep on getting the result within `print("not getting firebase token")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `getIdToken` method is an asynchronous call. Any code that needs the resulting token, needs to be inside the completion handler.

So something like:

```
FirebaseToken.shared.getIdToken(token: {tokenId, error in
    guard let tokens = tokenId else {return}
    headers = [
        .authorization(bearerToken: tokens),
        .accept("application/json")
    ]
    guard let headerAuth = headers else {
        print("not getting firebase token")
        return
    }

    session.request(url, method: apiMethod).validate().responseDecodable(of: [T].self) {(response) in
        switch response.result{
        case .success:
            guard let users = response.value else {
                return
            }
            completionHandler(users, nil)
        case .failure(let error):
            completionHandler(nil, error)
        }
    }

})
```

I also removed this line:

```
guard let errors = error else {return}
```

As I'm pretty sure this returns out of the block when there is **no** error.

Comment: I have changed the code like so but it seems like the asynchronous call isn't being run, can you help me in knowing how to fix this. Thank you.